# How to trigger client side validation of RegularExpressionValidator?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use RegularExpressionValidators for the input text-boxes in my ASP.NET forms.

The GUI appears like. All the items are server controls and upon leaving the text box, I would display error message if the input is invalid.

I have enabled client-side validation with EnableClientScript in the RegularExpressionValidator. Once I leave the text box, it immediately fires the validator. But upon clicking on any button (causes to generate postback) removes the regular expression validators error display from the screen. How can I retrigger the client validation?

I am a newbie with asp.net

```
---------------------------
|                         | * Invalid input
---------------------------

Listbox A           Listbox B
------------       ------------
|          |       |          |
|          |       |          |
|          |   >>  |          |
|          |       |          |
|          |       |          |
------------       ------------
```

Code goes like this.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="nameBox" runat="server" CssClass="StandardTextBox" Width="297px"
        EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regExpValidatorRuleName2" align="left" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="nameBox" 
        Width="10px" Height="10px" 
        CssClass="StandardErrorLabel"
        Display="Dynamic" 
        ErrorMessage="Input has Invalid character(s). Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, @, ., -"
        ValidationGroup="EditingPanel" 
        ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*$" 
        ToolTip="Input has Invalid character(s). Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _, @, ., -">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:Panel ID="criteriaPanel1" GroupingText="Test" runat="server"
        left="19px" CssClass="InputPanelTableLeft" Width="400px" Height="470px" Font-Bold="True"
        Font-Size="X-Small">
        <table class="InputPanelTable">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:ListBox ID="listboxA" Rows="10" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
                        Width="150px" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px" valign="middle">
                    <asp:Button ID="buttonMove" runat="server" OnClick="buttonMove_OnClick"
                        Text="&gt;&gt;" ToolTip="Moves selected item from left side to right" />
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <asp:ListBox ID="listboxB" Rows="10" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
                        Width="150px" Height="100px"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that ***buttonMove*** is causing postback when clicked on it.

Validation controls' error messages cannot persist uding postbacks.

You have not mentioned what to move from ListBox A to ListBox B.

Hence, if you can move elements from ListBox A to ListBox B using JavaScript (I mean, don't use serverside program), your problem can be solved.

Please let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I can use client-side scripting to solve this but there are data sources attached to the listboxes. In that case, things are not working well. Is it possible to solve this using `UpdatePanel`? @ashokkumar

Comment: UpdatePanel also causes postbacks but the only difference is that postback happens asynchronously. You have mentioned that data sources have been attached to listboxes. Even then you can use javascript to move elements from ListBox A to ListBox B. For your requirement, moving elements from ListBox A to ListBox B should happen only thru JavaScript, but no other go. Let me know with some sample data if you want to know how to move data in ListBoxes using Javascript.

Comment: I have managed to write the code using Javascript to move the data between but unfortunately the data source causes some problems... ListboxA contains data which is retrieve from DB and attached as data source to it. it contains simple text ("1","2" will also do).

Comment: I couldn't conclude/understand anything from your reply. Are you facing problem with loading data into ListboxA? How may I help you?

Comment: Thanks for the helping hand... :) 

Can you help with how data sources behaves when you work with client side javascript?

Comment: Your question is so ambiguous. :-) Look at this URL whether it could be helpful to you. http://how-to-asp.net/listbox-losing-values-postback/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24947/discussion-between-ashok-kumar-and-sarat)

Comment: I could not identify new in your question. I spent lot of time in the chat window for your reply, but could't get. Might be some network delay. I have got serious instructions from stackoverflow saying like more comments should not be added. I left chat window since I became busy with my work.